# Conversion from string "Label9" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have made a tableadapter query that displays the result on the label9.text
but i need to make a ifelse statement where if the label9.text <= 0 then it will display a messagebox.

```
    Dim red = Me.SlpdetailsTableAdapter.ScalarQuery2(Label7.Text)
    Dim pay = Label9.Text

    If pay <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("This Loan is already fully paid", "Paid")
    Else

        Label9.Text = red
        Label10.Text = Val(Label9.Text) - Val(Label8.Text)
        Me.SlpsummaryTableAdapter.UpdateQuery2(Label10.Text, Label7.Text)
        Me.SlpdetailsTableAdapter.InsertQuery(Label7.Text, Label6.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, Label8.Text, Label10.Text, remtxt.Text)
        Try
            remtxt.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        MessageBox.Show("Loan Payment is added", "Added")
        Me.Close()
        SLPDetail.SlpdetailsTableAdapter.FillBy(SlpdbDataSet.slpdetails, Label7.Text)

    End If
```

Comment: I don't see any error in the code you have posted (besides some bad code habits). You should provide some more context for your question. Have you debugged the code? VS will surely tell you in which exact line the error happens. Knowing that is sohuld be easy to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure label9.text is getting value ..then try parsing it to double as below and try

```
 Try
            Dim pay As Double = Double.Parse(Label9.Text)

            If pay <= 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("This Loan is already fully paid", "Paid")
            Else
                ''Do what ever you want
            End If
        Catch e As Exception

            ''error means label9 text is not valid numeric value
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong value", "Not Valid Pay value")

        End Try
```